# PHP: How to prevent multiple execution of a code (if it is already in process)

Tags: php, mysql, cron

#### Explanation

An API call (to another service) which usually takes 10-20 seconds to respond is stored in database,

After it is stored, System will try to use the API instantly to show the result to user, but it might fail (and display that it failed but we will try again automatically), therefore there is also a `Cron Job` set to run every 30 seconds and try the (failed) queries again.

If the API return success (whether in instant usage or using Cron Job) the flag is changed to success in database and it will not run again.

#### Issue

My problem is while the `Instant Call` to API is in process, the `Cron Job` might also try another call as it is not yet flagged as successful,

Also in rare cases, while the previous Cron Job is in process, the next Cron Job might run the code again.

#### What I have already tried to prevent the issue

I tried storing `In Process` API calls in a database table with `Status=1` and delete them when the API call was successful or set status to 0 if it failed,

```
 if ($status === 0)
 {
     
     // Set Status to 1 in Database First (or die() if database update failed)
     
     // Then Call The API

     // If Failed Set Status to 0 so Cron Job can try again
     
     // If Successful Change Flag to success and remove from queue

 }
```

> But what if the `Instant Call` and the `Cron Job Call` happen at the exact same time? they both check if status is 0 which it is, then both set status to 1 and execute the API Call...

#### Questions

1. Is what I have tried the correct way to handle this?
2. Should I worry about them happening at the exact time (the issue i explained in the Yellow Quote above) if there are a lot of calls (sometimes +500/sec)

#### Update Before Bounty

Isn't there really an easy way to handle such cases on the PHP side? if not, which way is better in experts' opinion? below are some methods but none of them are detailed enough and none of them have any Downvotes/Upvotes.

P.S. There are many updates/inserts to database, I don't think locking is an efficient idea and I'm not sure about the rest of ideas.

Comment: You'll want to read up on semaphores. I just recently solved something similar using `flock()`, even though that may not be the most elegant solution.

Comment: Why don't cron job check `In Process` status too?

Comment: In Process is not a lock certainty. no different than checking status=0

Comment: @umka It already does, the code above is the same on Instant Run and Cron Jon Run, but what if `Instant Call` and `Cron Job` run at the `exact same time`?

Comment: A good idea would be to use Message Queues like IronMQ.

Comment: @Ara, to prevent a job running the same time, first it should update a flag: `UPDATE table SET flag='In Process' WHERE flag!='In Process'`, then check if the number of affected rows is `1`, and then do the job.

Comment: @umka Checking the affected rows is actually pretty smart, maybe you can post it as an answer if you have time?

Comment: please check my answer it works and its standard php/linux way of solving this

Comment: updated with working php code

Answer (score 18):

This is exactly why [Semaphore](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php) was created for.

In php, it can be used in the following way : 
Using semaphores in PHP is actually very straight forward.  There are only 4 semaphore functions:

```
sem_acquire() – Attempt to acquire control of a semaphore.
sem_get() – Creates (or gets if already present) a semaphore.
sem_release() – Releases the a semaphore if it is already acquired.
sem_remove() – Removes (deletes) a semaphore.
```

So how do they all work together?

1. First, you call `sem_get()` to fetch the identifier for the semaphore.
2. After that, one of your processes will call `sem_acquire()` to try and acquire the semaphore. If it’s currently unavailable, `sem_acquire()` will block until the semaphore is released by another process.
3. Once the semaphore is acquired, you may access the resource that you are controlling with it.
4. After you are done with the resource, call `sem_release()` so that another process can acquire the semaphore.
5. When all is said and done, and you’ve made sure that none of your processes require the semaphore anymore, you can call `sem_remove()` to remove the semaphore completely.

You can find more information and example about this in [this article](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores).

Comment: Semaphores will work when processes are running on the same machine. They are probably better to be used for access to local machine resources like files. You also need to deal with crashed processes.

Comment: @alex347 yeah, this is a big deal with semaphore, if a process crashes without releasing the semaphore, it's game over... Using try/catch/finally is highly recommanded to always release the semaphore before crashing... only a `kill -9` may cause an instant kill and so no time to release anything before dying... but there is no solution for this... What is the solution for remote processes ?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that these beautiful methods does not work on Windows and some WebHosting providers.

Answer (score 5):

what I do in scripts is
(pseudocode)

```
SCRIPT START
LOCK FILE 'MYPROCESSFILE.LOCK'
DO SOMETHING I WANT
UNLOCK FILE 'MYPROCESSFILE.LOCK'
SCRIPT END
```

So if the file is locked the second (duplicated) process wont run (will lock/halt/wait) UNTIL the file is UNLOCKED by the original process.

**EDIT updated with WORKING PHP code**

```
<?php

    class Locker {

        public $filename;
        private $_lock;

        public function __construct($filename) {
            $this->filename = $filename;
        }

        /**
         * locks relevant file
         */
        public function lock() {
                touch($this->filename);
                $this->_lock = fopen($this->filename, 'r');
                flock($this->_lock, LOCK_EX);
        }

        /**
         * unlock above file
         */
        public function unlock() {
                flock($this->_lock, LOCK_UN);
        }

    }

    $locker = new Locker('locker.lock');
    echo "Waiting\n";
    $locker->lock();
    echo "Sleeping\n";
    sleep(30);
    echo "Done\n";
    $locker->unlock();

?>
```

Comment: just save this to file as locker.php, run php locker.php, and in another window php locker.php you will see one is sleeping other is waiting

Comment: What about multi server applications? This will work when all php scripts are located on the same server only.

Comment: @Prozi Thank you very much, What happens if they both run at the exact same time? (I already can handle the issue if the next code runs for example 10ms after the first)

Comment: read about PHP function flock(), A starts, B starts, A locks file, B waits because of lock, A finishes, B locks file, B finishes

Comment: Great Solution @Prozi helped me with my similar issue

Answer (score 2):

You need a proper queuing solution here. You can implement it yourself using a queue table and table locks to avoid different processes picking up the same job.

So you can pick up tasks from the queue table like this:

```
LOCK TABLES table WRITE;
SELECT * FORM table WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 1;
set status = 1 for the selected row
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Locking the table will ensure that other processes don't do SELECTs and don't pick up the same row from the table.

Inserting the job to the queue as simple as this:

```
INSERT INTO table (job_id, status) VALUES(NULL, status);
```

Removing the job after processing is completed:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE job_id = 12345;
```

Comment: Thanks, This actually seems simpler/more understandable than the other ways to me, but what will happen to my inserts? if I try to INSERT another API Call to this queue table while its locked, will my INSERT query fail (and I have to show Failed error to user)? or will it wait in MySQL queue and happen after unlock so no `Query Failed` errors in php side? (user is waiting to see the result). Can't we just lock SELECTing this Query and allow inserts?

Comment: This will lock tables for any queries (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc). Only the process which acquired the lock will be able to work with the table. Queries from other processes will not fail, they will wait until table becomes unlocked. If table is locked for more than something like 50 seconds (depends on your server configuration) then you may hit a lock timeout (mysql error 1205). In that case you'll just need to restart your query or increase the timeout setting in the config.

Comment: actually the default lock timeout is 31536000 seconds or one year, so you shouldn't hit that error

Comment: @alex347 What a strange default timeout... if a process gets locked for 1 year, there *may* be a problem indeed !

Comment: @Random Mysql timeouts can be configured from php. If you have a simple table for the queue purposes only and use the queries I provided, the table will not be locked for longer than a second or so, usually it is just milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

On each cron job start check whether the lock file exist or not if exit exit if not crate lock file in some temp directory after completion of api process un-link this file.

Comment: can u just try Peterson two process solution for critical section problem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm

Comment: I don't know How is this any different than what i have done? (setting and checking status === 1 and 0 in database) what if they both check at the same time when the file doesn't exist, then both of them try to create the lock file?

Comment: Have you followed Perterson's algorithm link?.  Store flag1, flag2, turn in separate table for shared access purpose and follow the process one and process 2 algorithm , it will insure that one process is running at a time. I think this should work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you should know the times that the cron will run (say every 5 min) then for your user requested function could you check to see if the system time is exactly when a cron should be running?  That would at lest prevent them from running at the exact same time.

Comment: what a siren go off in the building every 30 seconds. should drastically improve worker performance !

Answer (score 1):

I use this on Linux to see if a script is running when multiple execution needs to be avoided:

```
$output = array();
exec('pgrep -fl the_script.php', $output);
```

Then scan through `$output` and determine if it is already in progress.

For instance, here is copy/paste of existing code:

```
$exec_output = array();
exec('pgrep -fl archiver.php', $exec_output);
$pid_count = 0;
foreach ($exec_output as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    if (basename($parts[2]) == 'archiver.php') $pid_count++;
}
```

Then do things based on `$pid_count`. The `basename()` check is to make sure I don't catch some other thing like `special_archiver.php` or whatever might exist. You can check for the full path as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Semaphores](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php) can be installed in php, and for signal control at a kernel level, it will control process locking atomically.  Unix was designed to use this mechanism alongside other methods like [signals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) for interprocess communication.  Not sure you need to get that sophisticated.

It may work looking at the output of ps -ef but it may be subject to system load and process priority. You may find it works using a database flag, but why add overhead? Databases can get busy.

I would think a simple file is probably less prone to latency issues when you want to make 500 checks per second.

e.g. if the cron script starts with

```
if ( ! -f otherprocessisrunning)
then
   // create/open the file
   > cronprocessisrunning

   // when cron process finishes
   // it removes the cronprocessisrunning file
   rm -f cronprocessisrunning
else 
   sleep for 2 minutes
   call this function
fi
```

and the other script has the same behaviour in php that does this

```
if (! file_exist(cronprocessisrunning))
    > otherprocessisrunning
    start the other process
    when it is finished, remove otherprocessisrunning
endif
```

It should be fast enough as creating file handles (with no content) translates to a simple system call.  If it is not, try it in bash shell.

Comment: Why would you charge the server so much (500 checks / second !) when you already had the correct way in the first place : using semaphore ? :)

Comment: Sure, Semaphores are a correct solution.  This method would be (I think) more successful than some of the up-voted ideas which appear to work but (like this) are not well controlled ways of multitasking latch control.  But if it can be done without installing the Semaphores module (which may be tricky on shared hosting, etc.), then I would flag it as an inode, rather than a DB entity or inspecting the text output of ps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can be a good way:

```
temp_queue Table
-----------------------
id --> Int, Index, Autoincrement
query_id --> Int (your query ID or something to identificate a specific query)
in_use_by --> varchar (cron or api)
```

**Cron job:**

*Script starts*

```
SELECT in_use_by FROM temp_queue ORDER_BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

if results != 0 return;

INSERT INTO temp_queue SET query_id=SOME_ID, in_use_by = 'cron';
SELECT in_use_by FROM temp_queue ORDER_BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Then check the last SELECT results

```
if in_use_by == 'cron' continue
else return
```

When the execution ends:

```
DELETE FROM temp_queue WHERE query_id=SOME_ID
```

**API job:**

*Script starts*

```
SELECT in_use_by FROM temp_queue ORDER_BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

if results != 0 return;

INSERT INTO temp_queue SET query_id=SOME_ID, in_use_by = 'api';
SELECT in_use_by FROM temp_queue ORDER_BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Then check the last SELECT results

```
if in_use_by == 'api' continue
else return
```

When the execution ends:

```
DELETE FROM temp_queue WHERE query_id=SOME_ID
```

---

What happen if the Cron Job & API try to call the query at exactly same time? They both will check for the 1st writed line with query_id=SOME_ID so only 1 of they with continue.

Yes, a lot of selects, inserts and deletes. But it works.

**What do you guys think about that?**